# How to make my server in my Docker container reload with changes

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, nodemon

I have created a simple app connected with PostgreSQL and pgAdmin, as well as a web server in a Docker images running in a container.

My question is how I can make it reload, like with nodemon in a local server, without the need of deleting the container everytime.

I have been trying different solutions and methods I have seen around but I haven't been able to make it work.

I have already tried inserting the command: ["npm", "run", "start:dev"] in the docker-compose.file as well...

My files are:

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM node:latest

WORKDIR /

COPY package*.json ./
COPY . .
COPY database.json .
COPY .env .

EXPOSE 3000

CMD [ "npm", "run", "watch ]
```

**Docker-compose.file**

```
version: '3.7'
services:
    postgres:
        image: postgres:latest
        environment:
            - POSTGRES_USER=test
            - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=tes
            - POSTGRES_DB=test
        ports:
            - 5432:5432
        logging:
            options:
                max-size: 10m
                max-file: "3"
    pgadmin:
        image: dpage/pgadmin4
        environment:
            - PGADMIN_DEFAULT_EMAIL=test@gmail.com
            - PGADMIN_DEFAULT_PASSWORD=pasword123test
        ports:
            - "5050:80"
    web:
        build: .
        # command: ["npm", "run", "start:dev"]
        links:
        - postgres
        image: prueba
        depends_on: 
        - postgres
        ports: 
        - '3000:3000'
        env_file:
        - .env
```

**Nodemon.json file:**

```
{
    "watch": ["dist"],
    "ext": ".ts,.js",
    "ignore": [],
    "exec": "ts-node ./dist/server.js"
  }
```

**Package.json file:**

```
  "scripts": {
    "start:dev": "nodemon",
    "build": "rimraf ./dist && tsc",
    "start": "npm run build && node dist/server.js",
    "watch": "tsc-watch --esModuleInterop src/server.ts --outDir ./dist --onSuccess \"node ./dist/server.js\"",
    "jasmine": "jasmine",
    "test": "npm run build && npm run jasmine",
    "db-test": "set ENV=test&& db-migrate -e test up && npm run test && db-migrate -e test reset",
    "lint": "eslint . --ext .ts",
    "prettier": "prettier --config .prettierrc src/**/*.ts --write",
    "prettierLint": "prettier --config .prettierrc src/**/*.ts --write && eslint . --ext .ts --fix"
  },
```

Thanks

Comment: "Nodemon in a local server" sounds like a good solution to me.  Docker is intentionally designed so that the container environment is isolated from your host code, and is intentionally designed so that the image needs to be rebuilt and the container recreated if the code changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `COPY . .` command only runs when the image is built, which only happens when you first run `docker compose up`. In order for the container to be aware of changes, you need the code changes on your host machine to be synchronized with the code inside the container, even *after* the build is complete.

Below I've added the volume mount to the web container in your docker compose and uncommented the `command` that should support hot-reloading. I assumed that the source code you wanted to change lives in a `src` directory, but feel free to update to reflect how you've organized your source code.

```yaml
version: '3.7'
services:
    postgres:
        image: postgres:latest
        environment:
            - POSTGRES_USER=test
            - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=tes
            - POSTGRES_DB=test
        ports:
            - 5432:5432
        logging:
            options:
                max-size: 10m
                max-file: "3"
    pgadmin:
        image: dpage/pgadmin4
        environment:
            - PGADMIN_DEFAULT_EMAIL=test@gmail.com
            - PGADMIN_DEFAULT_PASSWORD=pasword123test
        ports:
            - "5050:80"
    web:
        build: .
        command: ["npm", "run", "start:dev"]
        links:
          - postgres
        image: prueba
        depends_on: 
          - postgres
        ports: 
          - '2000:2000'
        env_file:
          - .env
        volumes:
          # <host-path>:<container-path>
          - ./src:/src/
```

If that isn't clear, here's an article that might help:

https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/how-to-enable-live-reload-on-docker-based-applications/

Comment: Thank you very much! Now when deleting the container and creating it again all the changes are shown without the need of deleting and loading the image again.

But I am still not getting the changes "without" deleting the container... 

How could I do it ?

Comment: Are you making changes inside the `./src` folder? Have you tested the `npm run start:dev` command without docker to make sure it reloads as you would expect?

Comment: Yes I have. I have the command "watch" for my ts files in my src folder and the command start:dev for my js files in my dist folder.

So in the dockerfile and docker-compose file I could put as well "watch" or "start:dev"

Comment: Now I am confusing in what to put in my volumes, as my directory folder is called "starter" and then I want Docker to watch for "dist" folder.
What would me postgres and my web volumes be

Comment: If the `npm run start:dev` command only watches the dist folder then its that folder you'll have to mount as a volume, not the `src` directory. Are you planning on running the ts watch command from outside of docker on your host machine?

Comment: Yes, that is correct. I still can't make it work... 

Maybe it has somethign to do with the dockerfile?